# Call UINavigationController from subview in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, subview, modalviewcontroller

I have a table view in which I have subclassed the cells. In these cells I add a subview of a UIView. When sliding the cell I add another UIView to the subclass of UITableViewCell.

I would like to present a ModalViewController when pressing a button inside the second UIView (subview in UITableViewCell). I do not have a navigation controller in this view, therefore I am passing the navigation controller from the view controller my table view is inside of and down to my second UIView.

Here, I call it as you normally would but nothing happens.

```
ComposeCommentViewController *ccvc = [[ComposeCommentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeCommentViewController" bundle:nil];
[navController presentModalViewController:ccvc animated:YES];
```

Does anyone have an idea what I might do wrong or have another solution?

**EDIT:** This is how I set `navController`

First I pass it to my subclass of UITableViewCell.

```
if (feedCell == nil)
{
    feedCell = [[FeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    [feedCell setNavigationControllerForSlidedView:[self navigationController]];
}
```

The subclass has the method `setNavigationControllerForSlidedView:` which looks like this:

```
- (void)setNavigationControllerForSlidedView:(UINavigationController *)navController
{
    [feedSlidedView setNavController:navController];
}
```

In my `FeedSlidedView` I have declared and synthesized `UINavigationController *navController;`

Comment: Of course. I have added it to the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are going about this runs contrary to MVC (model-view-controller) design practices. You have a number of mechanisms for accomplishing what you want within the MVC framework that Apple provides in its SDK. Probably the simplest, in my opinion, would be to add a target-action to the button in the subview of your UITableViewCell. In your view controller's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, add something like the following:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(presentComposeComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In this case, `self` would be the UIViewController that is responsible for the UITableView in question. You would then include the method for the selector above in that view controller:

```
- (void)presentComposeComment:(id)sender {
    ComposeCommentViewController *ccvc = [[ComposeCommentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeCommentViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:ccvc animated:YES];
}
```

Note that I am not sending the `presentModalViewController:animated:` message to the navigation controller, but rather the view controller.

Comment: The subview in my UITableViewCell does not respond to `presentModalViewController:animated:` since it is a subclass of UIView (I'm doing this because I need to use `drawRect:`) Your example would definitely be the best way but sadly, it's not possible in this case. Do you know if there is another way to call the UIViewController responsible for the UITableView?

Comment: If you look at my answer above, I stated that the presentComposeComment: method goes in the UIViewController responsible for the UITableView. The UIViewController is the target for the button and the UIViewController is where you need to place the presentComposeComment: code.

Comment: Okay, I tried that but I am not sure if I understand what you mean. I placed `presentComposeComment:` in the view controller in which my table view is. In my UITableViewCell I called the button in the subview and added a target to it like this: `[[feedSlidedView composeButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(presentComposeComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` when doing this, my application will crash with an `Unrecognized selector sent to instance.` `self` is the instance of the cell.

Comment: Don't place the code for adding the target-action to the button inside your custom UITableViewCell. Place that code inside your view controller - `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a good place for that.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! That makes sense. Thank you very much for your help and your patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Note that you should send the addTarget:action:forControlEvents: message to the button when you create a new cell, but not when you re-use an existing cell - since the button in an existing cell will already have that target-action set.